# Service to ASP.NET Communication

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

A little background... I have a .NET webpage that communicates one way with a service. (using OnCustomCommand())  When the user presses a button, a function is called.  Which is all good and dandy, however when the function is done executing I need to be able to send a message, function call, or some communication to the .NET webpage.

Is there a way for my service to call a function, send message or update my .Net webpage?

I've looked around and seen mostly .NET -> Service but nothing seems to go the other way.

EDIT:  Its a windows service, and the ASP page and WindowsService reside on the same server.

Comment: service - Windows service or webservice?

Comment: When you say "update my .NET webpage"? Do you mean you want to trigger the server side ASP.NET code or you want the browser on the user end to display an update?

Comment: Either or...when the service is done running I want to essentially want the user to be notified that the service is done.

Comment: So from your web app you use ServiceController.ExecuteCommand() to trigger some action in the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the service write the output to a common area... such as a shared file, or a database.  Then refresh the webpage and have it query that file for the response output.

Support more than one user you should have have some session ID that will be used to determine where the output is saved.  For example, call a command line parameter with a GUID like this:

```
 Echo This is a test > c:\Some Directory\Session12345.txt
```

And then have your aspx page query and refresh using a GET like this http://example.com/GetOutput.aspx?Session=12345

From there use ASP to access a file with an appended SessionID in the URL.

You can extend this concept to work with JQuery and WCF as needed. Of course, you will need to add security to this to prevent MITM attacks.  But it sounds like this is a small project not connected to the internet so the extra features may not be that important.

Comment: Okay great.  Will this allow the page to be updated live?  Say the user keeps the window open, and the service finishes.. will this update asap? or will I have to query every so often to get an update?

Comment: And yes, it is a small internal project I am working on.  Just accessible on the local network.

Comment: Yes you will have to poll to get the output.  For example you could write to a file called `sessionDone12345.txt` and if it exists, stop refreshing, or doing the jquery.  Easy way might be to just set the `Meta` refresh tag of the page

Comment: Okay cool.  Thank you!  I'm not sure if its possible but do you happen to know how to do it without refreshing the page?

Comment: You can create a WCF service with HTTPGet enabled.  Then use Javascript on the client side to query WCF.  This would be good for another question...

Comment: @TxAG - Learn JQuery (what you will use to do HTTPGet) free for the next 36 hours: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/02/23/36-hour-free-offer-jquery-fundamentals-training.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Communication can only be done from client to server. Use Ajax/webservice/scriptmethod for retrieving status of service call.

Comment: Thank you! Is that hard to implement?

Comment: This type of questions is always hard to answer without knowing of application requirements, complexity etc. But generally it is pretty easy if you have used webservices/Ajax in past.

Comment: I have almost zero experience with webservices/Ajax... Where would be a good place to start?